# How can I place label after image component?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

```
    <s:Label y="77" textAlign="center"  color="#737373" fontSize="10" text="{_data.name}" horizontalCenter="0" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold"/>
    <mx1:Image id="previewGroup" width="20"  source="/flex_bin/img/icons/prewiew-icons.png" />

    </s:Group >
```

I want to place image at label end point...How can i do it with Flex 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<HGroup y="77" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Label textAlign="center"  color="#737373" fontSize="10" text="{_data.name}" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold"/>
    <s:Image id="previewGroup" width="20" source="/flex_bin/img/icons/prewiew-icons.png" />
</HGroup>
```